# Python does not read all lines of CSV file

Tags: python, text-files, export-to-csv

```
00,0,6098
00,1,6098
00,2,6098
00,3,6098
00,4,6094
00,5,6094
00,6,6094
00,7,6094
00,8,6094
```

That's a snip from my csv file. The file contains about 465 lines but when I read it only 380 lines are read. Here's my code:

```
import csv
import itertools
 with open('lala.csv', 'r') as in_file:
    lines = in_file.read().splitlines()
    stripped = [line.replace(","," ").split() for line in lines]
    grouped = itertools.izip(*[stripped]*1)
    with open('lala.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        for group in grouped:
            writer.writerows(group)
file=open( "lala.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(file)
for line in reader:
    print(line[2])
```

Comment: your original text file looks like csv to me... what is your desired output?

Comment: Look at what 380, 381 lines look like, is there a blank line?

Comment: Are line breaks consistent throughout the file? Can you add debugging prints with `len(lines)`, `len(grouped)` and `len(reader) #I'm not 100% sure this will work`? Why don't you just use `csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=',')` and `csv.writer(out_file, delimiter='\t')`?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Also The len(lines) shows 380 however,the original file has 460 lines

Comment: why you are not using pandas library for reading csv files ?

Comment: It gives the same error

Comment: Whether the original file has a blank line in the middle

Comment: No, the original file does not have a blank line in the middle